# Use of the Cartesian product and combinations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, combinations, binomial-coefficients, education

I have found this question on a textbook of high school (first year - 14 years old) where there is the Cartesian product topic.

[image]

This question there is in the "prove Invalsi" tests for students of 13 years ("terza media") old where they didn't study the Cartesian product in an insiemistic sense. Look the [question](http://www.webtutordimatematica.it/images/pdf_vari/invalsi_matematica_2013-2014_terza_mod.pdf) $D20$ to the pag. 17.

Luisa can't quite remember the combination of the lock
of her bicycle. The combination is obtained by turning four small wheels,
each bearing all the digits from 0 to 9. Luisa does not remember
the second digit of the combination at all but knows that:

- the first digit is 6;
- the third digit is 3 or 4;
- the last digit is 1.
  How many combinations at most will Luisa have to try to succeed in opening the lock on her bicycle?

I have done this:
The combinations with the third digit 3 are ten.
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|} 
\hline 6 & 0 & 3 &1\\ 
\hline 6 & 1 & 3 & 1\\ 
\hline 6 & 2 & 3 & 1\\
\hline 6 & 3 & 3 & 1\\
\hline 6 & 4 & 3 & 1\\
\hline 6 & 5 & 3 & 1\\
\hline 6 & 6 & 3 & 1\\
\hline 6 & 7 & 3 & 1\\
\hline 6 & 8 & 3 & 1\\
\hline 6 & 9 & 3 & 1\\
  \hline
\end{array}
With the same mechanism the combinations with the third digit 4 are ten.

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|} 
\hline 6 & 0 & 4 &1\\ 
\hline 6 & 1 & 4 & 1\\ 
\hline 6 & 2 & 4 & 1\\
\hline 6 & 3 & 4 & 1\\
\hline 6 & 4 & 4 & 1\\
\hline 6 & 5 & 4 & 1\\
\hline 6 & 6 & 4 & 1\\
\hline 6 & 7 & 4 & 1\\
\hline 6 & 8 & 4 & 1\\
\hline 6 & 9 & 4 & 1\\
  \hline
\end{array}

In total I have **20** combinations.

> How I can find the $20$ combinations using combinatorial calculus and especially using the Cartesian product? I don't know how to put the digits in the $x-$ and $y-$axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are $4$ digits, the number of possibilities is actually a $4$-fold cartesian product
$$
D_1 \times D_2 \times D_3 \times D_4, 
$$
where $D_n$ is the set of possible digits in position $n$, i.e.
\begin{align} 
D_1 &= \{6\} \\
D_2 &= \{0, 1, \dots, 9\} \\
D_3 &= \{3, 4\} \\
D_4 &= \{1\}
\end{align}
so the number of possibilities is
$$
|D_1 \times D_2 \times D_3 \times D_4| 
= |D_1| \cdot |D_2| \cdot |D_3| \cdot |D_4| 
= 1 \cdot 10 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 20.
$$

Of course it's difficult to visualize a $4$-dimensional array, but fortunately, when one or more of the sets has only a single element, we can essentially ignore it. In this exercise, $|D_1| = |D_4| = 1$. In fancy set theory terms, there's a bijection
$$
D_2 \times D_3 \;\to\; D_1 \times D_2 \times D_3 \times D_4 
$$
mapping $(d_2, d_3) \mapsto (6, d_2, d_3, 1)$. So we can enumerate this $2$-fold cartesian product instead, and this array can be drawn on the plane.

[image: Cartesian product as dots.]

Comment: thank you very much. grazieeeeeeeeeee